# Change a file in a particular commit

Tags: git

I need to see if I can modify a file in a particular commit.  I have a release posted on github that points to a commit.  The release was a while back.  Problem is a 3rd party dep changed in a way it should not have and breaks that release.

I just need to make a one line change to a file, but I am not sure if that is possible and still have the release point to the same commit but with the file changed.

Also don't want to screw up my repo.  Not a git expert by any means.  Please help.

Comment: Surely this situation is an example of why you have minor version releases as a follow up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't condone this, here's what you'd do:

```
$ git checkout 1.0
```

Now make your change to the file and save it. Then:

```
$ git commit -am "Fixed some bug"
$ git tag 1.0 -f
$ git push origin --tags -f
```

Obviously replace `1.0` with whatever your release is.

Comment: 'While I don't condone this, here's what you'd do'  Fully agree this is 100% the wrong thing to do.  Problem is I already did something I should not have and this is my way out ;)  Thanks for the help and I will never do this again :)